# Python Pygame Project Automation Stops Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pygame, game-physics

I am trying to create a project on Pygame. The idea is to create an traditional snake game having the capability to play on its; i.e., The snake is smart enough to hit the boundary and plays on.
Until now I have created a whole game which is able to understand the boundary by calculating the next position of snake; i.e., trajectory on XY plane by determining next move of snake by calculating next pixel position of snake in every direction.

```
def nextMove(snake_head,x1_change,y1_change):
        
    x1=snake_head[0]
    y1=snake_head[1]
    next_left=x1-10
    next_right=x1+10
    next_top=y1-10
    next_down=y1+10
```

So my window size i determine is 600 x 400 so whenever snake is willing to hit wall the value becomes either zero or max of window resolution.

So when this happen I tell my code to change its path to different direction i.e logic

```
def nextMove(snake_head,x1_change,y1_change):
        
    x1=snake_head[0]
    y1=snake_head[1]
    next_left=x1-10
    next_right=x1+10
    next_top=y1-10
    next_down=y1+10
    #print(next_left,next_right,next_top,next_down)
 
    if next_left<0:
        x1_change=10
        y1_change=0
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
    if next_right>= dis_width:
        x1_change=-10
        y1_change=0
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
    if next_top<0:
        x1_change=0
        y1_change=10
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
    if next_down>=dis_height:
        x1_change=0
        y1_change=-10
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change    
    return x1_change,y1_change
```

Where `x1` was the previous position of a snake of windows and `x1_change` and `y1_change` is updating the snake position chaining to main function as well as this one.

Now although I declared the logic the code was running perfectly fine
but when I append the direction change logic to a new function to make a code compact and movable. I.e.,

```
def Leftmove():
    x1_change=-10
    y1_change=0
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def Rightmove():
    x1_change=10
    y1_change=0
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change
    
def Topmove():
    x1_change=0
    y1_change=-10
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def Downmove():
    x1_change=0
    y1_change=10
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def nextMove(snake_head,x1_change,y1_change):
        
    x1=snake_head[0]
    y1=snake_head[1]
    next_left=x1-10
    next_right=x1+10
    next_top=y1-10
    next_down=y1+10
    #print(next_left,next_right,next_top,next_down)
 
    if next_left<0:
        Rightmove()
    if next_right>= dis_width:
        Leftmove()
    if next_top<0:
        Dowsnmove()
    if next_down>=dis_height:
        Upmove()    
    return x1_change,y1_change
```

By appending this new function or lines of codes the code stops working
now I don't know what's missing. I you figure it out here please let me know. Further suggestions and improvements are most welcome.

the full code is mentioned below:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import math

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)

dis_width = 600
dis_height = 400

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snake_block = 10
snake_speed = 15

font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)


def Your_score(score):
value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, yellow)
dis.blit(value, [0, 0])



def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
for x in snake_list:
    pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])
    
    
    
def Leftmove():
x1_change=-10
y1_change=0
x1+=x1_change
y1+=y1_change
return x1_change,y1_change

def Rightmove():
x1_change=10
y1_change=0
x1+=x1_change
y1+=y1_change
return x1_change,y1_change

def Topmove():
x1_change=0
y1_change=-10
x1+=x1_change
y1+=y1_change
return x1_change,y1_change

def Downmove():
x1_change=0
y1_change=10
x1+=x1_change
y1+=y1_change
return x1_change,y1_change

def nextMove(snake_head,x1_change,y1_change):
    
x1=snake_head[0]
y1=snake_head[1]
next_left=x1-10
next_right=x1+10
next_top=y1-10
next_down=y1+10
#print(next_left,next_right,next_top,next_down)

if next_left<0:
    Rightmove()
if next_right>= dis_width:
    Leftmove()
if next_top<0:
    Dowsnmove()
if next_down>=dis_height:
    Upmove()    
return x1_change,y1_change



    

def message(msg, color):
mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])


def GameBody():
while game_close!=False:
    dis.fill(blue)
    message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", red)
    Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                game_close=False
                game_over = True
                return game_close,game_over
            if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                GameBody()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x1_change = -10
                y1_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x1_change = 10
                y1_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y1_change = -10
                x1_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y1_change = 10
                x1_change = 0
    
    
    
    
    if x1 >= dis_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= dis_height or y1 < 0:
        game_close = True
    x1 += x1_change
    y1 += y1_change
    return x1,y1
    
    dis.fill(blue)
    pygame.draw.rect(dis, green, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
    snake_Head = []
    snake_Head.append(x1)
    snake_Head.append(y1)
    snake_List.append(snake_Head)
    #print(snake_Head)
    #print(snake_List)
    if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
        del snake_List[0]

   # Snake Hits Its Own Body    
    """
    for x in snake_List[:-1]:
        if x == snake_Head:
            game_close = True

    """
    our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
    x1_change, y1_change = nextMove(snake_Head, x1_change, y1_change)
    Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
    pygame.display.update()
    
        
    #calculating distance
    def Distance():
        x=snake_Head[0]
        y=snake_Head[1]
        dis_fleft=foodx-x
        dis_fright=foody-y
        dis_food=foodx-x+foody-y
        print(dis_fleft,dis_fright,dis_food)
    Distance()

    

    if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
        foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
        foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
        Length_of_snake += 1

    clock.tick(snake_speed)

game_over = False 
game_over = False
def gameLoop():

x1 = dis_width / 2
y1 = dis_height / 2

x1_change = 0
y1_change = 0

snake_List = []
Length_of_snake = 1

foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0

while game_over!=True:
    GameBody()      
pygame.quit()
quit()


gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I might be wrong and might have missed something, but in the `leftmove`, `rightmove`, `topmove` and `downmove` functions you are updating the value of the `x1`, `y1`, `x1_change` and `y1_change` variables but you are not passing them as parameters so you would be getting an error. Also since those function are returning the value of `x1_change` and `y1_change`, in the `next_move` function you should do `x1_change, y1_change = leftmove()` because then the `nextmove` is also returning the value of `x1_change` and `y1_change`.
Please let me know if i am wrong.